# how can i plot probability distribution of my classes in the way below?

Tags: classification, xgboost, probability, matplotlib

All,

I would like to plot the following:

[image]

I have a binary classification problem where I am using xgboost as my 'model' below:

```
y_pred = model.predict_proba(x_test)[:, 1]

probabilities = pd.DataFrame({
            'prediction': y_pred,
            'output': y_true
        })


        colors = ['g', 'r']
        for output in [0, 1]:
            probabilities[probabilities['output'] == output]['prediction'] \
                .plot(kind='kde', ax=ax2, legend=True, color=colors[output])
        ax2.set_xlim(prob_xlims)
        ax2.set_xlabel('Predicted probability')
        ax2.set_title('Predicted probabilities and true labels (color)')

        # Legend
        handles, labels = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
        ax2.legend(handles, ['Class 0', 'Class 1'])
```

Using the above how can I get a plot similar to the above? Correct me if wrong as well, but `predict_proba` returns $\text{probability(class x | data sample)}$ where data sample is a single row of data..?